# Error in OBIEE 12c invoke java method via agent to send report to another server

Tags: java, obiee

I want to send a report via agent to a file system but I am getting the 'error looking up EJBs' as shown in the screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Action Framework expects EJBs to be deployed to the default location of /ejb. The mappedName annotation of the Session bean must preceded by a ejb/

A simple google search yields this: https://gerardnico.com/dat/obiee/obips/action_ejb